# Microsoft Graph API Online Meeting Delete not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I successfully created an online meeting with the following API.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/onlineMeetings
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "startDateTime":"2019-09-09T14:33:30.8546353-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2019-09-09T15:03:30.8566356-07:00",
  "subject":"Application Token Meeting",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I am trying to delete the meeting its not working. I tried with the following APIs:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/{meeting id}
```

and

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{user id}/onlineMeetings/{meeting id}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The api documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-delete?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) works for me, eg:

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f_19:meeting_M2IzYzczNTItYmY3OC00MDlmLWJjMzUtYmFiMjNlOTY4MGEz@thread.skype
```

I get an http 204 in response.

Note that even after deleting the meeting using the above api, I am still able to join the meeting from the teams client, this may be a different bug perhaps.  However, trying to delete the same meeting id again gives a 404 not found, which is expected.